# ElasticSearch boundary_chars not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following index:

```
{
  "myindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "todo" : {
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the following document:

```
{
  "_index" : "myindex",
  "_type" : "todo",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "title" : "That means that when used for instance in combination with a phrase query, it will highlight all the terms that the query is composed of, regardless of whether they are actually part of a query match, effectively ignoring their positions."
  }
}
```

Now I'm making the following query:

```
{
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {
        "fragment_size": 150,
        "boundary_max_size": 100,
        "boundary_chars": ",",
        "type": "fvh"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "type": "phrase",
        "query": "all the terms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns a highlighted fragment which is like this:

```
for instance in combination with a phrase query, it will highlight <em>all the terms</em> that the query is composed of, regardless of whether they are actual
```

I would expect the highlighted fragment to 'break' upon hitting the defined boundary_char ','. So what I would want the highlight to look like is this:

```
it will highlight <em>all the terms</em> that the query is composed of
```

Why does the actual highlighted fragment contain parts that are before and after a boundary char? Is this not how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?